# what is the best way to string overload on a Moose attribute accessor?

Tags: perl, moose

I have a class where I want to apply string overloading on its `id` attribute. However, Moose doesn't allow string overloading on attribute accessors. For example:

```
package Foo;
use Moose;
use overload '""' => \&id, fallback => 1;
has 'id' => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'Int',
    default => 5,
);

package main;
my $foo = Foo->new;
print "$foo\n";
```

The above will give an error:

```
You are overwriting a locally defined method (id) with an accessor at C:/perl/site/lib/Moose/Meta/Attribute.pm line 927
```

I have tried a couple of options to get around this:

1. Marking `id` `is => bare`, and replacing it with my own accessor: `sub id {$_[0]->{id}}`. But this is just a hack.
2. Having the string overloader use another method which just delegates back to id: `sub to_string {$_[0]->id}`.

I'm just wondering if anyone has a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
use overload '""' => sub {shift->id}, fallback => 1;
```

Works fine for me.

Comment: Which is essentially option 2 from the question in shorter syntax. I'm not saying it's bad but it would still be interesting to know why the first approach from the question fails.

Comment: The shorter syntax is slightly cleaner. With the 3 arg issue, I guess this has to be the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you are getting an error because `\&id` creates a placeholder for a sub to be defined later, because Perl will need to know the address that sub will have when it is defined to create a reference to it. Moose has it's own checks to try to avoid overwriting methods you define and reports this to you.

Since I think what you really want to do is call the `id` method when the object is used as a sting like so:

```
use overload '""' => 'id', fallback => 1;
```

From the [`overload` documentation](http://p3rl.org/overload)

> Values specified as strings are interpreted as method names.

Comment: It doesn't work. I'm still getting error message: `Cannot assign a value to a read-only accessor at reader Foo::id (defined at - line 4) line 3
        Foo::id('Foo=HASH(0x12ffa10)', undef, '') called at - line 12`

Comment: @Hynek, it looks like `overload` is passing parameters to the method, which Moose interprets as an attempt to set the attribute.  So you'll need to use an intermediary sub, as you did in your answer.

Comment: I see that this error is because `overload` always passes 3 args to the method from [Overload - calling conventions](https://metacpan.org/module/overload#Calling-Conventions-and-Magic-Autogeneration)